# Typespec declaration for a passed function's return value

Tags: elixir

So let's say that I have a function like this:

```
def something(callback) do
  case *some condition* do
    0 ->
     :ok
    1 ->
      {:error, :foo}
    _ ->
      callback.()
  end
end
```

where the callback function can return either `:ok` or `{:error, *some atom*}` where **some atom** is an unknown atom.

Now, I am wondering if there is a way to write the spec for the `something/1` function that doesn't use the general `atom` spec. So, the question is, basically, if there is a way to write a more specific typespec than this:

```
@spec something(() -> :ok | {:error, atom}) :: :ok | {:error, atom}
```

Instead, I would like my spec to show that `something/1` function can return `:ok`, `{:error, :foo}` or the value returned by `callback`

PS I know that this kind of thing doesn't' matter on the practical level so it's just a question based on curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for type variables. Erlang [does support](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html#id80676) declaring them but dialyzer does not seem to be doing any checks based on these types at the moment (Erlang/OTP 20).

> Type variables can be used in specifications to specify relations for the input and output arguments of a function. For example, the following specification defines the type of a polymorphic identity function:
>
> ```
> -spec id(X) -> X.
> ```

The type signature you want is:

```
@spec something(() -> t) :: :ok | {:error, atom()} | t
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could define a `@type` for the return type of `callback/0`, e.g. `@type callback_return_type :: atom` and then use: `@spec something(fun()) :: :ok | :error | callback_return_type`

> PS I know that this kind of thing doesn't' matter on the practical
>   level so it's just a question based on curiosity.

Typespec composability does matter in larger projects to ensure consistency and to avoid code duplication. Types that you declare in a `module` can be reused by other `modules` and you can even declare certain `typespecs` to be `private` and `opaque`, giving you fine granular control over how they are to be utilized and so that you can maintain separation of concerns for library users for instance.

Comment: I am afraid you didn't understand my question. My question is how to avoid using general `atom` spec and say that the return error atom can be either `:foo` (which is returned by `something/1` itself) or the error atom that `callback/0` can return. So I need to somehow bind the error return spec for `callback/0` and error return spec for `something/1`. `atom` works, obviously, but I wonder if there is a way to narrow it down.

Comment: @JustMichael Thank you for voicing your concern but in itself I do not belief I have misunderstood your question. Your question boils down to the reuse of types that you have declared earlier and how to compose them, which I have demonstrated accordingly. After all your feedback, the only thing I would change is to be hyper specific to your specific use case, e.g. `@type callback_return_type :: :ok | {:error, atom}` `@spec something(fun()) :: :ok | {:error, :foo} |  callback_return_type` but that doesn't make my answer invalid, right?